# frequency of oscillation of the disk

Tags: vibration

The mass m is suspended by a string from a disk
circular homogeneous of mass mc and radius R, as illustrated in figure 24. The disk is restricted from rotating by a spring attached to it at a distance cr of its center of rotation. If mass m undergoes a downward displacement x, determine the frequency of oscillation of the disk.

[image]

[image]

Can someone explain to me why m*x and J*teta are in that direction (have positive sinal) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of:

- positive axis is **arbitrary** (whether up/down or left/right as positive does not make a difference in the solution).
- direction of unknown vector quantities is also **arbitrary**. i.e. you draw the unknown quantity as positive or negative and if the equations are properly constructed then the sign will indicate the true direction.

---

The most common problem in dynamics problems is what happens with derived quantities  e.g. moment of an unknown force. More specifically, if it required to determine the moment of a $m\ddot{x}$ term (which describes an "active" force), then depending on the position of the $m\ddot{x}$  relative to the point that the moments are calculated the resulting moment can have a positive or negative sign.

An additional example --which commonly produces confusion -- is the term $J \cdot \ddot{\theta}$. Although the positive direction for $\theta$ is defined as ClockWise(CW), the moment is positive for CounterClockWise (CCW). So in this case, I suspect what is happening is that whoever drew the diagram drew the term $J \cdot \ddot{\theta}$ as positive with respect to the moment positive.

---

Apart from that I am not certain that in this problem you can ignore gravity. Which means that the force on the rope will not be equal to $m\cdot \ddot{x}$  (it can actually be derived by $m\cdot g -T = m\cdot \ddot{x}$).

Also, I agree with you that $\ddot{x}$ should be pointing downwards, if $\theta $is rotating counterclockwise (unless $\dot{\theta}$ is too large).

However, in general it will be very difficult to decypher what was the exact methodology that the person used to derive the equation (or his/her intent),without a more detailed explanation of the solution.   .

Answer (score 0):

If we set x down as positive, $j \ddot\theta$ and $kyR_c$ should have negative signs.

Because when the mass m accelerates down, those two resist its acceleration.